# Laravel 4 validators - Validate one of two fields

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Is there any generic Laravel validator option that allows me to do the example below?

Example: I have two text boxes, at least one of them must be filled. One has to be compulsorily filled, but not required are the two filled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like Laravel has some built-in rules: `required_without` and `required_without_all`.

**[required_without:foo,bar,...](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-required-without)**

> required_without:foo,bar,...
>   The field under validation must be present only when any of the other specified fields are not present.

**[required_without_all:foo,bar,...](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-required-without-all)**

> required_without_all:foo,bar,...
>   The field under validation must be present only when the all of the other specified fields are not present.

So in your validation you do:

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    [
        'textbox1' => Input::get('textbox1'),
        'textbox2' => Input::get('textbox2'),
    ],
    [
        'textbox1' => 'required_without:textbox2',
        'textbox2' => 'required_without:textbox1',
    ]
);
```

Comment: Just to clarify, "must be present only" means "is mandatory". The field being validated as required_without_all can ALSO be present when the other fields are set.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I think a little hack is easier than extending the `Validator` class:

```
if(empty(Input::get('textbox1')) && empty(Input::get('textbox2'))) {
    $v = Validator::make([], []); // Pass empty arrays to get Validator instance

    // manually add an error message
    $v->getMessageBag()->add('textbox2', 'Required if textbox1 is empty!');

    // Redirect back with inputs and validator instance
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors($v)->withInput();

}
```

So, if both fields are empty then after redirecting, the second text box (`textbox2`) will show the error message `Required if textbox1 is empty!`. But it could be done using conditional validation too:

```
$v = Validator::make([], []); // Pass empty arrays to get Validator instance

// If both fields are empty then textbox2 will be required
$v->sometimes('textbox2', 'required', function($input) {
    return empty(Input::get('textbox1')) && empty(Input::get('textbox2'));
});

$messages = array( 'required' => 'Required if textbox1 is empty!' );
$v = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);
if($v->passes) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that Laravel doesn't pass input to the validator when a field is empty. So it doesn't seem possible to create a nice rule to cope with this situation without overriding how the Validation class works. 

This is probably the best solution.

Comment: `required` is the exception, if you don't set a field as required then Laravel assumes that a null or empty value is ok. This makes it hard to make a rule like `require_one:field2,field3`. If you check the `validate` method in the Validation class it is commented as so `Unless the rule implies that the attribute is required, rules are not run for missing values.`

Comment: What you are actually talking about, check this code by yourself. Both works. Check one example [here](http://heera.it/laravel-manually-invalidate-validation#.U6D_GPmSySo). `Laravel` doesn't pass the empty fields and that's why it works for `required`.